# How to divide a pair of Num values?

Tags: class, function, haskell, subclass, division

Here is a function that takes a pair of Integral
values and divides them:

```
divide_v1 :: Integral a => (a, a) -> a
divide_v1 (m, n) = (m + n) `div` 2
```

I invoke the function with a pair of Integral
values and it works as expected:

```
divide_v1 (1, 3)
```

Great. That's perfect if my numbers are always Integrals.

Here is a function that takes a pair of Fractional
values and divides them:

```
divide_v2 :: Fractional a => (a, a) -> a
divide_v2 (m, n) = (m + n) / 2
```

I invoke the function with a pair of Fractional
values and it works as expected:

```
divide_v2 (1.0, 3.0)
```

Great. That's perfect if my numbers are always Fractionals.

I would like a function that works regardless of whether the
numbers are Integrals or Fractionals:

```
divide_v3 :: Num a => (a, a) -> a
divide_v3 (m, n) = (m + n) ___ 2
```

What operator do I use for *_*?

Comment: Please note that `div` and `/` do _genuinely different_ things, which is why they've got different names. There's no way to implement `/` and stay in an Integral data type unless you want a world of errors. Haskell is doing the right think by making you think before you write and decide what you really want. I think you should be able to decide whether you want Int, Integer, Rational, Double or whatever. If you're trying to do something generic, reconsider whether division really can be treated generically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on what AndrewC said, div doesn't have the same properties that / does. For example, in maths, if a divided by b = c, then c times b == a. When working with types like Double and Float, the operations / and * satisfy this property (to the extent that the accuracy of the type allows). But when using div with Ints, the property doesn't hold true. 5 `div` 3 = 1, but 1*3 /= 5! So if you want to use the same "divide operation" for a variety of numeric types, you need to think about how you want it to behave. Also, you almost certainly wouldn't want to use the same operator /, because that would be misleading.

If you want your "divide operation" to return the same type as its operands, here's one way to accomplish that:

```
class Divideable a where
  mydiv :: a -> a -> a

instance Divideable Int where
  mydiv = div

instance Divideable Double where
  mydiv = (/)
```

In GHCi, it looks like this:

```
λ> 5 `mydiv` 3 :: Int
1
λ> 5 `mydiv` 3 :: Double
1.6666666666666667
λ> 5.0 `mydiv` 3.0 :: Double
1.6666666666666667
```

On the other hand, if you want to do "true" division, you would need to convert the integral types like this:

```
class Divideable2 a where
  mydiv2 :: a -> a -> Double

instance Divideable2 Int where
  mydiv2 a b = fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b

instance Divideable2 Double where
  mydiv2 = (/)
```

In GHCi, this gives:

```
λ> 5 `mydiv2` 3
1.6666666666666667
λ> 5.0 `mydiv2` 3.0
1.6666666666666667
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Associated Types which allows for implicit type coercion and  are explained quite nicely [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/assoc-types/fun-with-type-funs/typefun.pdf).  Below is an example for the addition of doubles and integers.

```
class Add a b where
    type SumTy a b
    add :: a -> b -> SumTy a b

instance Add Integer Double where
    type SumTy Integer Double = Double
    add x y = fromIntegral x + y

instance Add Double Integer where
     type SumTy Double Integer = Double
     add x y = x + fromIntegral y

instance (Num a) => Add a a where
     type SumTy a a = a
     add x y = x + y
```